# How can i use calculated fields for sorting in Waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to sort my query for reddit hot algorithm. It is based on time and i can't use beforeUpdate or beforeCreate hooks. I need to sort with a calculation when im querying but i couldn't find a solution.

Let's say my model is looks like this;

```
var myModel = Waterline.Collection.extend({
  attributes: {
    up: {
      type: 'integer',
    },
    downs: {
     type: 'integer',
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create any kind of function helper or custom attribute inside your Model to help you make the right query.

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/README.md#custom-types